# Getting back to the toc by clicking on headlines in the text. How to do it?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, texshop

I am working with texshop which lacks of a proper navigation (or I didnt find it yet). To make it easier to navigate through the document I would like to make all the headlines clickable in a way that when you click on them you get back to the toc. Is there a way to do so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Preview menu there's the entry "Drawer"; it opens a panel where you find all bookmarks for the sectional divisions.

Comment: Once more you helped me so much. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm very sorry, I don't want to hijack this question, but I simply don't understand the answer... does it refer to a particular program? or does it refer to a way of having section titles link (hyperref-wise) to their "line" in the TOC? The latter I'd very much like to know how to do... should I ask a different question or is this the proper place to ask for elaboration?

Comment: @mpr The question refers to TeXShop on Mac OS X; but all serious PDF viewers have a panel for showing bookmarks.