# Linking the section text to the TOC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, hyperref, links

I'd like the section headings in running text to link to their "line" in the Table of Contents so as to get "two-way" navigation, eg: a user looks in the Table of Contents for a section title, jumps there, reads a couple of lines, clicks on the section title again and gets taken to the section's entry in the Table of Contents once more.

Any ideas? :)

(Somewhat related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22574/getting-back-to-the-toc-by-clicking-on-headlines-in-the-text-how-to-do-it))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's another approach, using the `titlesec` package and the `\hypertarget`, `\hyperlink` mechanism from `hyperref`. A little example showing the necessary settings for `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` and their starred versions:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ {\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\thechapter}}{20pt}{\hyperlink{chap-\thechapter}{\Huge#1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{chap-\thechapter}{}}}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{-20pt}{\Huge#1}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\hyperlink{sec-\thesection}{#1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{sec-\thesection}{}}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\hyperlink{subsec-\thesubsection}{#1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{subsec-\thesubsection}{}}}
\titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0pt}{#1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Numbered test chapter one}

\section{Test section one}

\subsection{test subsection one one}

\subsection{test subsection one two}

\chapter*{Unnumbered test chapter one}

\section*{Unnumbered test section}

\subsection*{Unnumbered test subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution indeed does work like a charm :) Still, I'm having problems trying to make it play nicely with the rest of my manuscript. I've chased the error down to the following line `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\texorpdfstring{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\arabic{chapter}}{\arabic{chapter}}}`, which basically gives me titling numbers in the sectionings (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31942/oldstyle-numbers-in-body-newstyle-numbers-in-section-headings). Should I mark your answer as accepted (it _does_ work)? do you have any ideas how to make both things "compatible"?

Comment: @mpr: see my updated answer. I redefined the font family for the chapter counter inside `\titleformat`, so there's no need to use the problematic `\renewcommand\thechapter{...}`.

Comment: It works like a charm in the MWE, but in my manuscript I get a gazillion warnings along the lines of "destination with the same identifier (num2) has been already used, dupicate ignored"... I even included all of the packages / commands I use in my manuscript into the MWE, it seems to me that it's a matter of page numbering or something... I modified your commands slightly, for example: `\hyperlink{subsec-\thechapter-\thesection-\thesubsection}{#1}` and `hypertarget{subsec-\thechapter-\thesection-\thesubsection}{}`

Comment: @mpr: then you will have to provide a minimal version of your code. You can edit your original question to add this minimal version.

Comment: I'm very sorry for all the back-n-forth! I found that the problem are `*` chapters / sections / subsections / etc. The MWE you propose fails with a duplicate warning.

Comment: @mpr: no problem. You need to provide also definitions for the unnumbered versions. I've edited my answer showing how to proceed.

Comment: Works... but now the breaking in the titles is off... I get tons of bad boxes :S  Still, this is golden as it is, the problem is most definitely on my side, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 11):

This solution sets up `\hypertargets` in the `toc` by renewing the `\contentsline` command. It links back to the `toc` by setting the section headings as `\hyperlinks` using the `titlesec` package. Note that each of the new `\hypertarget` start with the word 'toc'

You can easily copy this approach for `chapters` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % sample text
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} % to change headings
\usepackage{hyperref}

% renew \contentsline for toc to include hypertarget
\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline%
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
\hypertarget{toc#4}{}%
\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}

% renew \section to link to the toc
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsection.\thesection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}

% renew \subsection to link to the toc
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsubsection.\thesubsection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{my sub section}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[2]

\clearpage

\section{Third section}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

**Explanation**

Note that if you look at the `.toc` file for the above example you'll see the following entries

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}First section}{2}{section.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}my sub section}{2}{subsection.1.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}Second section}{2}{section.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}Third section}{3}{section.3}
```

The `\contentsline` takes four arguments, the fourth of which will uniquely identify each entry. I used this unique entry combined with the string 'toc' as the `\hypertarget{toc#4}{}`; it would not work without the additional string 'toc' (or something similar), as it would result in a duplicated `identifier` which would be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a very simple example of myself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand\section[1]{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{#1}{}}
    \oldsection{\texorpdfstring{\protect\hyperlink{#1}{#1}}{#1}}
    } %%

\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand\subsection[1]{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{#1}{}}
    \oldsubsection{\texorpdfstring{\protect\hyperlink{#1}{#1}}{#1}}
    } %%

\begin{document}
{
    \let\section\oldsection
    \pdfbookmark{Contents}{Contents} 
    \vspace*{.5cm}
    \tableofcontents
}
\clearpage

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{my sub section}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[2]

\clearpage

\section{Third section}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```