# hyperlink to the ToC page

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I want to have hyperlinks pointing to the ToC page. (In my MWE, the links are situated in the section titles, but it makes no difference for the discussion here). My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}[0]{\label{toc}\oldtableofcontents}

\begin{document}
First page\newpage
\tableofcontents\newpage

\section{Premier. Go to \hyperref[toc]{toc}}
\blindtext  \blindtext  
\section{deuxieme. Go to \hyperref[toc]{toc}}
\blindtext  \blindtext  
\section{Troisieme. Go to \hyperref[toc]{toc}}
\blindtext  \blindtext  
\end{document}
```

It works only partially: the links are there, but if I click on them, it goes to the "first page", instead of the ToC page.
I redefined `\tableofcontents`, in order to put a label juste before `\tableofcontents`, but I guess this is the problem. In the original command `\tableofcontents`, the must be at the beginning some initialisation, like `\newpage` or similar, which makes the problem.

Comment: You need a reference point. Therefore you can use `\phantomsection` or `hyperrlink`. Use `\phantomsection\label{toc}`.

Comment: ok, i think i understand. I thought `\label` create a reference point, but actually, it can only refer to a section, and not to any point in the text, am i right ?

Comment: [linking-the-section-text-to-the-toc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32495/linking-the-section-text-to-the-toc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` for placing targets and linking to them. You can use `\addtocontents` to write the `\hypertarget` into the .toc file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
First page\newpage
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{toc}{}}
\tableofcontents\newpage
\section[Premier]{Premier. Go to \hyperlink{toc}{toc}}
\blindtext  \blindtext  
\section[Deuxieme]{Deuxieme. Go to \hyperlink{toc}{toc}}
\blindtext  \blindtext  
\section[Troisieme]{Troisieme. Go to \hyperlink{toc}{toc}}
\blindtext  \blindtext  
\end{document}
```

Or, even better, place `\hypertarget` directly before `\tableofcontents`, but make `\clearpage` before.

```
\clearpage
\hypertarget{toc}{}
\tableofcontents
```

This ensures to link above the contents heading. The `\addtocontents` way places the target below the heading.