# Linking Section Titles to TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to make my document such that when you click on section or subsection titles in the main body, it will take you back to the TOC. I have implemented this as such:

```latex
\makeatletter
\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline%
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
    \oldcontentsline{#1}{\smash{\raisebox{1em}{\hypertarget{toc#4}{}}}#2}{#3}{#4}}%
\let\oldsection\section%
\renewcommand\section[1]{%
    \oldsection[#1]{\protect\hyperlink{tocsection.\thesection}{#1}}}%
\let\oldsubsection\subsection%
\renewcommand\subsection[1]{%
    \oldsubsection[#1]{\protect\hyperlink{tocsubsection.\thesubsection}{#1}}}%
\let\oldsubsubsection\subsubsection%
\renewcommand\subsubsection[1]{%
    \oldsubsubsection[#1]{\protect\hyperlink{tocsubsection.\thesubsection}{#1}}}%
\makeatother
```

Although it works, at the top of my TOC I get this:

[image]

I know it has something specific to do with the `\renewcommand\section`, because if I change that then it works fine.

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking the section text to the TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32495/linking-the-section-text-to-the-toc)